# Matplotlib save image with specific colours only

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the following example code to create image masks. The masks need to have one of 6 colours - 5 given colours and white background. However when I look at the unique colours of an image saved using code below, there are 25 colours generated. Using matplotlib is there a way to limit the colours generated on save?

```
def rect(x,y,w,h,c):
    ax = plt.gca()
    polygon = plt.Rectangle((x,y),w,h,color=c)
    ax.add_patch(polygon)

X = np.arange(0,10,0.1)   
F = np.zeros(int(len(X)/5))
for f in range(1,5):
    Fn=np.full(int(len(X)/5), f, dtype=int)
    F = np.append(F, Fn, axis=0)

Y = np.sin(X)
plt.plot(X,Y, alpha=0.0)
plt.xlim([0, 10])
dx = X[1]-X[0]

ccc = ['#996633','blue','yellow','red','green']
cmap = colors.ListedColormap(ccc[0:len(ccc)], 'indexed')
for n, (x,y, f) in enumerate(zip(X,Y,F)):
    color = cmap(int(f))
    rect(x,0,dx,y,color)
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig(f'5_colours_only.png', transparent = False, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
```

[image]

code to test image colours:

```
def get_unique_colours(img_name):
    im = pil_image.open(img_name)
    by_color = defaultdict(int)
    for pixel in im.getdata():
        by_color[pixel] += 1
    return by_color
```

Comment: Can you add the image that is generated with 25 colors?

Comment: Image added, bulk of colours are the 5 generated plus white but there are 160 pixels or so of nearly the same colour but not exacltly as specified.

Comment: Unless I’m mistaken they are occurring at the boundaries between colors?

Comment: Yes, may be due to antialiasing? I couldn't find a way to disable in matplotlib

Comment: `matplotlib.patches.Patch` objects have the bool keyword `antialiased`, assuming `rect` here is a `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` object (whose base class is `matplotlib.patches.Patch`) then you should be able to pass `antialiased=False` in their construction

Comment: Worked; I have added rect, code, plase add your comments to an anwer and I will accept to close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear the extra colors are generated by the antialiasing, [`matplotlib.patches.Patch`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib-patches-patch) objects (which `matplotlib.patches.Rectangle` objects inherit) support disabling this via the bool keyword [`antialising`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_antialiased), so

```py
plt.Rectangle((x,y),w,h,color=c,antialiased=False)
```

should prevent this.

This can also be done after construction via the method

```py
polygon.set_antialiased()
```